# Custom Guards only work when used at cmsComponents after Spartacus upgrade from 4.0 to 5.0, but Spartacus still works in Angular Routing

Tags: angularjs, spartacus-storefront

after the Spartacus update from 4.x to 5.0 the custom guards in my project only work if they are in the cmsComponents area. However, Spartacus custom guards still work if you put them in the Angular Routing, but there the custom guards don't work anymore.

It works but only when doing it like the 5.0 screenshots.

Here are some examples:

4.x:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHa4t.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Xmj.png)

5.0:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i7bO.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOzU0.png)

There is no indication in the 5.0 documentation that this has been changed, so why do custom guards not work in angular routing?